# NHibernate throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, nhibernate, exception

I have a WCF service using NHibernate, I am trying to connect this WCF service thru my WPF and get all the records from my SQL db. Some how it throws this exception and i don't have no clue about this.Any please give me a hand to sort this issue.

Exception :

> The type initializer for 'Gateway.DataAccess.NHibernateDAO.NHibernateHelper' threw an exception.

Resulting in:

> An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'Client.Modules.Metadata.ViewModel.StoriesViewModel'.

This my NHibernateHelper class

```
namespace Webster.Gateway.DataAccess.NHibernateDAO
{
    public sealed class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private const string CurrentSessionKey = "nhibernate.current_session";

        // An ISessionFactory is threadsafe, many threads can access it concurrently and request ISessions
        private static readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        // An ISession is a non-threadsafe object that represents a single unit-of-work with the database
        ////private static ISession currentSession; 

        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                return sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        static NHibernateHelper()
        {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem is with your configuration and not with this class

Comment: Thanks sleiman, what exactly I suppose look in too, u def make sense. This service use to work from when my friend publish the service but I do it throws this error.

Comment: Check inner exception details, NHibernate will normally give you a reasonable error - we need more details to help you

Comment: Catch the exception and post the `Exception.ToString()` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit,its nothing to do with my app,all i have to change the Application Pool setting in IIS and the Identity to my user name.I was hosting this WCF service in IIS.

It works fine now thanks a lot guys .